# Panframe 360 degree video sdk- PFObjectFactory.assetFromUrl Method first download then play

Tags: android, video, 360-degrees

I am using Pan frame 360 degree video sdk for playing 360 videos but when we are passing URL to method it is not playing as buffered, first it download all video then play, how to call to play buffered with progressive bar.
Please advise.

```
_pfasset = PFObjectFactory.assetFromUrl(this, url, this);
```

If i am using assetFromUri it play good.

Answer (score 1):

You should change something in your file play movie 360 degree.

```
public void loadVideo() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Initalizing", "while Loading...");
    _pfview = PFObjectFactory.view(this);
    _pfasset = PFObjectFactory.assetFromUri(SimpleStreamPlayerActivity.this, Uri.parse(videoUrl), SimpleStreamPlayerActivity.this);

    // Setting up View Mode & Aspect Ratio : @JB
    // @TODO Fix if newer version of PAN FRAME releases
    _pfview.setMode((viewMode >= 2) ? 2 : viewMode, 16 / 9);

    _pfview.displayAsset(_pfasset);
    _pfview.setNavigationMode(_currentNavigationMode);

    _frameContainer.addView(_pfview.getView(), 0);
}
```

Ref: You can find the Cordova Plugin for it [here](https://github.com/jumpbytehq/cordova-jb-plugin-panframe/blob/master/src/android/SimpleStreamPlayerActivity.java)